# Swift give back a value to tableview controller

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

i have a two TableView controllers. When i click on a cell I come to the second one. By clicking a cell in the second TableView, I want to give the value of this cell back to the first TableView Controller. So i have this code in the second TableView.

```
 let view = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("OverviewFine") as FinesOverviewTableViewController
 view.s_choosenPlayer = a_players[actualIndicator].PlayerName
```

Then I reload the data in the first TableView Controller.

```
 override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
 self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

But now, the variable "s_choosenPlayer" has the value "". What is the mistake?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're going back to your first controller, why are you instantiating a new instance of FinesOverviewTableViewController? If you wanted to go back to your house after work, would you have a new house built?

Comment: Normally no ;) Bitte how can i give back the a value to the presenting view?

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to do this is with delegation. When you segue from the first to the second controller, you implement prepareForSegue, and set yourself (the first controller) as the delegate of the second controller there. The second controller needs to define a delegate protocol, and call a method on its delegate when you click a cell there. Don't instantiate a new controller when you go back -- either dismiss or pop depending on what the forward segue was.